# Tenses to refer to the future

Tags: future-time

I would like to know if there are any other tenses or grammatical structures to use for speaking about the future apart from will (perfect tense included), going to, simple and continuous present.

I mean not the obvious ones. For example, simple present (I could never have imagined it could be used for the future).

> My mom arrives tomorrow.
>   I go to the doctor at 4 o'clock this afternoon.

Comment: TESOL has [a page](https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/future-tenses/) on that; it does not include all the ways, as there are probably at least a dozen. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/future-other-expressions-to-talk-about-the-future) talks about some more. Most websites talk about only three or four ways.

Comment: Questions should be about specific issues, not a list of every possible and/or obscure contingency.

Comment: English doesn't have a future tense. It uses will + [bare infinitive] , e.g. it will rain tomorrow to express future events

Comment: This is a page that is helpful for even native speakers: https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/tenses

Comment: @Giambattista Laymen have a more loose definition of what a "tense" is (for many of us native speakers, tense doesn't necessarily require inflection), kind of like how mathematicians define lines to be straight lines while in common parlance lines don't have to be perfectly straight.

Answer (score 1):

Though this isn't exhaustive, in addition to your simple future tense, there are also future perfect, future progressive, and future perfect progressive tenses. For example:

> We ***will walk*** (future {simple}) over the bridge and, once we're across it, we ***will have walked*** (future perfect) six miles. We ***will be walking*** (future progressive) all the way to the stadium, by which point we ***will have been walking*** (future perfect progressive) for over ten hours and covered more than ten miles.